# Unexpected EclipseLink shared cache behavior with java.util.Date fields

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, shared-cache

I'm kicking the tires on EclipseLink(2.3.0) and found something that seems severely wrong. The net of my problem is that when an Entity is returned from a shared cache hit, `java.util.Date`(and perhaps others) aren't copied as I would expect. This has some pretty nasty consequences as Date fields aren't immutable, and as such can't be shared.... but then again maybe I'm missing something? I'll note that I don't have any properties set, but I am using the `-javaagent` weaver in a JSE environment.

Test snippet:

```
// Setup
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Person p = new Person(2);
java.util.Date d = new java.util.Date();
p.setDate(d);

em.getTransaction().begin();
em.persist(p);
em.getTransaction().commit();
em.close();

// Get a fresh em
EntityManager em1 = emf.createEntityManager();

Person p1 = em1.find(Person.class, p.getId()); // cache hit
java.util.Date d1 = p1.getDate();

assertFalse(p == p1); // Make sure we have different entities
// The next line fails! For some odd reason different Entities are sharing the same date.
assertFalse(d == d1); // make sure each Entity instance has different date instances
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is described in the EclipseLink docs here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Application_Development_(ELUG)#Mutability

Short answer: most non serialized Basics are treated as immutable, but can be configured to be treated as mutable using the EclipseLink @Mutable annotation:
http://eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/a_mutable.htm

Comment: Wow! That is completely counter intuitive and doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Even worse, my application behaves differently when the cache is enabled vs disabled?!

Comment: Maybe.  From ORM though, tracking changes is expensive.  It is more efficient if the date is immutable, since it is hard to tell when the date internals change otherwise - attribute change tracking can't be used when it is something internal to the attributes that has changed.  Comparisons can use '==' and set the value in cached objects can can '=' if it is immutable.  Without a shared cache, reading in the object multiple times means getting a new instance each time - with their own date instance.  A shared cache reuses the same instance and its date object.

Comment: So you're saying that performance is more important than adhering documented APIs (Date and Calendar)? In my opinion, changing the definition (mutable vs immutable) of an object in a system to better support shortcomings in another implementation is 100% the wrong answer. I'm really stuck on the potential for cache vs no-cache having different behavior.<end rant> Thanks for the links though!